# Rails + ionic : input from ionic to rails backend = Can't verify CSRF token authenticity 400 bad request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an app both in ionic and rails. the idea is to have the rails as the backend, and ionic as the interface. I use jsonapi_resources gem for this project. the request works well in postman, however it keep gives me cors-preflight error. So I managed to resolve that by using rack-cors gem. Now the request do get through the rails app, now it just that I keep getting this csrf error.

application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < JSONAPI::ResourceController
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
  before_filter :allow_ajax_request_from_other_domains
  after_filter :set_csrf_cookie_for_ng

 def allow_ajax_request_from_other_domains
   headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = 'http://localhost:8100/'
   headers['Access-Control-Request-Method'] = '*'
   headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = '*'
   headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD'

 end

def set_csrf_cookie_for_ng
  cookies['XSRF-TOKEN'] = form_authenticity_token if protect_against_forgery?
end

protected

  # In Rails 4.2 and above
  def verified_request?
    super || valid_authenticity_token?(session, request.headers['X-XSRF-TOKEN'])
  end

  # In Rails 4.1 and below
  def verified_request?
    super || form_authenticity_token == request.headers['X-XSRF-TOKEN']
  end

end
```

app.js

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
  delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"];
  ...(routing details here)})
```

parts where I capture the input and post to the rails app:

```
$scope.item = {};
$scope.post = function(item){

  $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/tests',
    data: {"type":"tests", "attributes":{"names":"test from the other side"}},
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.api+json', 'Accept': 'application/vnd.api+json' }
  })

  console.log(item)
}
```

route.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".
jsonapi_resources :tests


  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
root 'welcome#index'

end
```

I have tried searching for answer, but I kept getting this error.